# Values in api come undefined

Tags: laravel

i am making a `GET` api in Laravel the api in postman works great but when i use it in Laravel to fetch specific data they come undefined. This is the `api.php` route:

```
Route::get('list',[GetController::class,'getValues']);
```

This is the `GetController` :

```
function getValues()
    {
        return response()->json([ValuesResource::collection(Order::all())], 200);
    }
```

This is the `ValuesResource` :

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
         return [
          'order_number' => $this->order_number,
          'client_id'  => $this->client_id,
          'description' => $this->description,
          'client' => new ClientResource($this->client),

        ];
    }
```

This is the `ClientResource` :

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
          return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'age'  => $this->age,
            'salary' => $this->salary,
        ];
    }
```

And this is the `blade JQuery` code :

```
async function getData() {
        const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/list";

        const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
        const barChatData = await response.json()
        console.log(barChatData);

        const salary = barChatData.map((x) => x.salary)

        //console.log(barChatData.map((x) => x.salary))

        const age = barChatData.map((x) => x.age)
        const name = barChatData.map((x) => x.name)

        employeeSalaryData = salary
        employeeAgeData = age
        employeeLabel = name
    }
```

In postman i get this result:

```
[
    [
        {
            "order_number": "b7f55e7ce5",
            "client_id": 1,
            "description": "order1",
            "client": {
                "name": "Mr. Omari Schaefer DVM",
                "age": "29",
                "salary": "150"
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

While on browser they come undefined, if i do just

```
console.log(barChatData);
```

I get this array

```
[Array(1)]
0
: 
Array(1)
0
: 
{order_number: 'b7f55e7ce5', client_id: 1, description: 'order1', client: {…}}
length
: 
1
```

So the values are coming but i cant fetch them with specific row.

Comment: possible that it may be due to scope of barChatData as its inside your getData() function 
write getData() on your browsers console to check .

Comment: @Sumitkumar i believe is how i use the `map(x)`

Comment: @Sumitkumar how i do that?

Comment: @Sumitkumar i get this if i write `getData()` on the browser console async ƒ getData() {
        `const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/list";

        const response = await fetch(apiUrl)
        const barChatData = await response.json()
        console.log(barChatData);`

Comment: @Sumitkumar what is this?

Comment: Your data is inside array which is inside another array, maybe it's that?

Comment: @StewieSWS maybe it can be that but how can i fix it as you can see i have posted all the codes

Comment: Maybe try something like barChartData[0][0]... instead of just barChartData

Comment: so when i do this ` console.log(barChatData[0][0])` i get an object : Object { order_number: "b7f55e7ce5", client_id: 1, description: "order1", client: {…} }
​
client: Object { name: "Mr. Omari Schaefer DVM", age: "29", salary: "150" }
​
client_id: 1
​
description: "order1"
​
order_number: "b7f55e7ce5"

Comment: @StewieSWS but still how can i fetch a single record from `barChatData[0][0]`

Comment: i got it its okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine but need a couple things to change as your fetched data is there.

there is array inside barChatData so map it like this:

```
const age = barChatData[0].map((item) => {
    return item.client.age;
});
const name = barChatData[0].map((item) => {
    return item.client.name;
});
const salary = barChatData[0].map((item) => {
    return item.client.salary;
});
```

Comment: i get this `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: barChatData[0][0].map is not a function`

Comment: i manage to get the values by doing this `console.log(barChatData[0][0].client.age)` but when i put it in the `const age = barChatData[0][0].client.age` still wont work

Comment: can you tell if both console.log and const age is in same function?

Comment: the const age gets the value but then the code makes error here  `employeeSalaryData = salary
        employeeAgeData = age
        employeeLabel = name`

Comment: is there a way to fix the code to not make values inside 2 arrays?

Comment: do a console.log like this in your function ````console.log(barChatData[0].map((item) => {
        return item.client.age;
    }));````

Comment: i got this `Array [ "29" ]
​
0: "29"
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []`

Comment: it worked i made that code in the const and worked